# unexpected namespace prefix with actionbar

Tags: android, namespaces, android-actionbar-compat

I am trying to implement the ActionBar through the support library, v7. Because I want to support the app for Android 2.1 (API level 7) and above.

I read in http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html following: "Using XML attributes from the support library Notice that the showAsAction attribute above uses a custom namespace defined in the tag. This is necessary when using any XML attributes defined by the support library, because these attributes do not exist in the Android framework on older devices. So you must use your own namespace as a prefix for all attributes defined by the support library."

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item        
        android:id="@+id/refresh"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_navigation_refresh"
        android:title="@string/refresh"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/> 
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="@string/settings"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/logout"
        android:title="@string/logout"
        myapp:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

Eclipse shows me the error "Unexpected namespace prefix "myapp" found for tag item". I don't see, what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I found something like a solution. If I clean my project, the errors disappear and I can start my app. But when I change something completly different in the xml and save it, the errors appear again and have to clean it again.

Answer (score 0):

**You have To Add The xmlns:tools as well as tools:context attribute for menu tag **

```
    <menu xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" tools:context="com.companyname.myapp.MainActivity">

    **Here in xmlns:context you have replace companyname and MainActivity as per need **

    **Other wise you have to clean and rebuild your project because IDE shows such error when they didn't got perfect project workspace OR module **
```